# Asymptotic order of the $L_\infty$ norm of asymptotically normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, asymptotics, high-dimensional

Let $\mathbf{X}_n \in R^p$ be a random variable and $\mathbf{s} \in \mathcal{S} = \{x \in R^p \ s.t. \ ||x||_2 = 1\}$. Then, suppose that $p$ and $n$ are allowed to diverge and that we have

$$\sqrt{n} \mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n \to \mathcal{N}(0,1),\;\; \text{(in distribution as } n \to \infty \text{)},$$

for all $\mathbf{s} \in \mathcal{S}$. Is there anything that can be concluded about the order of $||\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty}$?

My guess is that we should have $||\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty} = \mathcal{O}_p(\log(p)/\sqrt{n})$ but I can't show this formally.

Comment: I can't see how it would be $O_p( (\log p)/n)$ since that would fail even for $X_n\sim N(0,1/n)$ and $p=1$, where $\|X_n\|_\infty=O_p(1/\sqrt{n})$. Perhaps $O_p((\log p)/\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: Also, Ma and Kosorok (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-35/issue-4/Marginal-asymptotics-for-the-large-p-small-n-paradigm/10.1214/009053606000001433.full) have some closely related results, but assuming $X_n$ are actually means.

Comment: @ThomasLumley: Thank you very much for the reference. Indeed, there was a typo ($n$ instead of $\sqrt{n}$). I've edited the question.

Comment: Your hypothesis looks suspicious. Assuming $p > 1$, the statement $||\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty} = O_p(\log(p)/\sqrt{n})$ is equivalent to the statement $||\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty} = O_p(7/\sqrt{n})$, since $p$ is not a function of $n$. ($p$ must be the same for every element in the sequence $\mathbf{X}_n$ in order for there to be a single $\mathbf{s}$ such that $\mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n$ makes sense for all $n$.)

Comment: @fblundun Yes, in this case $p$ diverges with $n$. If $p$ is fixed we directely have $||\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty} = \mathcal{O}_p(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Then don't you actually have a 2-dimensional space of random vectors which should be called $\mathbf{X}_{p,n}$ rather than just $\mathbf{X}_{n}$?

Comment: I understand my notation may be confusing. $\mathbf{X}_n$ is a random variable in $R^p$ that converges in $n$ to normal in the sense given above.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify this point. Thanks

Comment: My answer assumes that for each $p$ you have an infinite sequence of random vectors of length $p$. Is that actually the intention? If not then what do "$p$ and $n$ are allowed to diverge" and "$p$ diverges with $n$" mean? It can't be that you are considering a single sequence of random vectors of increasing length since this is not consistent with the fact that the vector length has to be fixed in order for the set $\mathcal S$ to be defined.

Comment: To clarify no, you don't have for each $p$ an infinite sequence of random vectors of length $p$. Instead you have a random variable of length $p$ which increases with $n$. Below is reference to better understand these "high-dimensional" asymptotic regimes (see e.g. the discussion below Theorem 2.2). https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X99918730

Comment: You said that $\sqrt n \mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n$ converges in distribution. This statement cannot mean anything unless you have an infinite sequence of random vectors of equal length, since $\mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n$ is only defined if $\mathbf{s}$ and $\mathbf{X}_n$ have equal length, and the length of $\mathbf{s}$ is fixed in the context of the statement.

Comment: Yes, this is possible since $\mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n \in R$ for all $p$ (and $n$). See the paper I mentioned for a clearer explanation.

Comment: I am unable to make sense of this setup because there is no information about how $p$ and $n$ might be related.

Comment: Dear @whuber, the information on how $p$ is related to $n$ comes from $\sqrt{n} \mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ but is case by case. For example, in a logistic regression we have $\sqrt{n} \mathbf{s}^T (\hat{\beta} - \beta_0) \to \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ if $p^2 \log(p)/n \to 0$ and some technical requirements (see e.g. example 3 in the paper I mentioned above). I understand that this setup is complex but I would appreciate if you could re-open this question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to prove any statement of the form $||\mathbf{X}_{p,n}||_{\infty} = O_p(f(p, n))$. I haven't seen $O_p$ notation with more than one variable (here $n$ and $p$) before, so I'm going to assume the definition is:

> For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $M, N, P > 0$ such that for all $n > N, p> P$,
> $$
> P(||\mathbf{X}_{p,n}||_{\infty} > M |f(p, n)|) < \epsilon
> $$

But the only constraint given in the problem is that for each $p$, for each $\mathbf s$,

$$
\sqrt{n} \mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_{p,n} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1),\;\; \text{(in distribution)}
$$

The problem is that these convergences in distribution may not happen "in sync" for different $p$. For example, I don't see anything in the problem statement that rules out the behaviour

$$\mathbf{X}_{p,n}^{(1)} \sim \mathcal N(n^{p!},p^{n!}) \text{ whenever p > n}$$

where $\mathbf{X}_{p,n}^{(i)}$ is the $i$-th component of $\mathbf{X}_{p,n}$. This behaviour would rule out any reasonable $O_p(f(n,p))$ convergence result, because it would mean that no matter how big you choose your $N, P$, it will still be the case that $\mathbf{X}_{P+N+2,P+N+1}$ behaves ridiculously.

(Note that I am not assuming that $\mathbf{X}_{p,n}^{(i)} = \mathbf{X}_{p+1,n}^{(i)}$.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it is possible to get such results. For example, suppose that $\sqrt{n} \mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ for all $\mathbf{s} \in \mathcal{S}$, then we have $\mathbb{E}[||\sqrt{n} \mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty}] \leq \sqrt{2 \log(p)}$. Thus, we get $||\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty} = \mathcal{O}_p(\log(p)/\sqrt{n})$. However, in my question I didn't assume that $\sqrt{n} \mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ but only that $\sqrt{n} \mathbf{s}^T \mathbf{X}_n$ goes to a normal... In that case, I'm not sure what can be shown.

Comment: Of course it's possible to prove such results if you change the assumptions from which you're working! I'm addressing what can be shown based solely on the premises you actually included in your question.

Comment: Yes, of course you are right. Just wanted to show that you can get a results of the form $||\mathbf{X}_n|| = \mathcal{O}_p(f(n,p))$...

Comment: @user304347 From the result $E(||\sqrt{n}\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty}) \le \sqrt{2\ln(p)}$ (I suppose it's correct) you can't not deduce that $||\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty} = \mathcal{O}_p(\ln(p))$ (you fixed $n$ here, so it is a constant, and put it in the $\mathcal{O_p}$ is unnecessary). You can only conclude  $E(||\sqrt{n}\mathbf{X}_n||_{\infty}) = \mathcal{O}_p(\ln(p))$  (with the expectation $E$ outside)